# deep pressing of disc brake lever when whee not in position

Tags: repair, brake-rotor

I would like to know what happens when the disc brake lever is deeply pressed when wheel is removed.

Does it cause any damage? If yes then what should be the repair and how much it may cost?

Update: It is a motor bike. The wheel is placed back in place. The problem now is the disc pads are brushing against the rotor causing more friction and restricting the free wheel motion. What could be the possible reason for this behavior. Is there any chance of air getting into the braking system?

Comment: Pads might stick together , you ll need to detach them using a screwdriver.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about *just* the wheel/tire, or are you suggesting removing any part of the braking system as well? If just the wheel/tire, there is no worry.

Answer (score 2):

Depends upon the type of vehicle .

If you have a car where the brake assembly is independent of the wheels , you do not have an issue whatsoever.

on the other hand if you have a motorbike which has the rotor(the disc) attached to the wheel , if you depress the brake , the pads will stick together preventing you from reinstalling the wheel back into the assembly.

Solution is to take a flat headed screwdriver and separate the pads then insert the rotor in place.

Comment: Good point about a motorbike. I guess the OP should really clarify exactly what type of vehicle they are actually asking about.

Comment: I think only motorbike made some sense  :-)